# How to get value from dynamic control in gridview using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have one dynamic gridview contains one textbox.when user lost focus from the textbox, i want to get the value using javascript.for that i am using onblur() event in the textbox.but i'm not able to get the value .please find the code below

```
 function validateintforDWOnblur(input) {
    var row = input.parentNode.parentNode;
    var rowindex = row.rowIndex;
    var totaldw = document.getElementById('<%=gdvaddmsrcrt.ClientID%>').rows[rowindex].cells[2].innerHTML;
    var totaldw1 = document.getElementById(totaldw.id).value;
    var dw = document.getElementById('<%=gdvaddmsrcrt.ClientID%>').rows[rowindex].cells[3].innerHTML;
    return true;
}
```

textbox inside the gridview

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtdiswei" runat="server" onblur="javascript:return validateintforDWOnblur(this)" Width="100px" Text='<%# Bind("DW") %>' Height="40" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
```

Please help me to sort this out.

Comment: Why are you not able to get the value? What is stopping you?

Comment: where is validateintforDWOnblur function?

Comment: @ben if i'm doing like this in totaldw getting html of textbox control from the cell.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that it is what you want but why don't you try

```
var value = document.getElementById('<%=yourTextBox.ClientID%>').value;
```

so for your table you can pass the `ClietnId` property from eachRow and use it in the javascript function

```
function doSomething(idOfTheTextBox){
   var value = document.getElementById(idOfTheTextBox).value;
}
```

in html

```
 onblur="doSomething('<%# this.ClientID %>')
```

if you build server side your rows you can do the following

```
TextBox txt = new TextBox();
txt.ID = "something1";
txt.Text = "text";
txt.Attributes.Add("onBlur","doSomething('" & txt.ClientID & "')");
CellOfTheGrid.Controls.Add(txt);
```

Comment: given textbox in a  dynamic gridview.so its id is keep changing when i'm adding new row.i want to use all the value from that row.so how can i get the values from the row.